# elements counter with filter in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays and need to return map object with elements and counters. It almost done, but i stuck at counter - it always "undefined" for elements with counter>1. Can anyone help me?

```
const stopWords = ['', 'a', 'the', 'and', 'or'];
const pageWords = ['HellO', 's', 'And', 'hellO', '', 'AnD', 'NAME', 'oR', 'apple', 'HELLO', 'aPple'];

const wordsCount = (words, stopWords) => {
  const all = new Map();
  const arr = words.map(word => word.toLowerCase())
    .filter(word => !stopWords.includes(word))
    .reduce((acc, word) => {
         const count = all.has(word) ? acc[word] + 1 : 1;
         all.set(word, count);
         return acc;
    }, {});
   return all;
};

//what I need:  [['hello', 3], ['s', 1], ['name', 1], ['apple', 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're super close. I believe the only issue with your existing code is how you're accessing the current count of the `word`. Instead of using `acc[word]` you should use `all.get(word)` to access the existing count. Like this:

```js
const stopWords = ['', 'a', 'the', 'and', 'or'];
const pageWords = ['HellO', 's', 'And', 'hellO', '', 'AnD', 'NAME', 'oR', 'apple', 'HELLO', 'aPple'];

const wordsCount = (words, stopWords) => {
  const all = new Map();
  const arr = words.map(word => word.toLowerCase())
    .filter(word => !stopWords.includes(word))
    .reduce((acc, word) => {
         const count = all.has(word) ? all.get(word) + 1 : 1;
         all.set(word, count);
         return acc;
    }, {});
   return all;
};

console.log(Array.from(wordsCount(pageWords, stopWords)))
```

Also, this change means you no longer need the `acc`, so instead of a `reduce` I think a `forEach` makes the code a bit easier to read. Like this:

```js
const stopWords = ['', 'a', 'the', 'and', 'or'];
const pageWords = ['HellO', 's', 'And', 'hellO', '', 'AnD', 'NAME', 'oR', 'apple', 'HELLO', 'aPple'];

const wordsCount = (words, stopWords) => {
  const all = new Map();
  words.map(word => word.toLowerCase())
    .filter(word => !stopWords.includes(word))
    .forEach(word => {
      const count = all.has(word) ? all.get(word) + 1 : 1;
      all.set(word, count);
    });
  
  return all;
};

console.log(Array.from(wordsCount(pageWords, stopWords)));
```